# Finding the number of nodes at a given depth in a tree

Tags: java

I'm Having a little bit of trouble understanding why my recursive method for a problem isn't working. Its a method meant to produce the number of nodes at a given depth in a binary search tree. I've been given test cases, and I'm having an issue where for a test case on a tree I am getting the correct answer for one depth but the wrong answer for another depth on the same tree. I'm confused why I'm getting two different answers even is the answer is incorrect. My code and the test code is attached below.

Tree Structure

```
        D
       / \
      B   F (get correct output for this depth) (depth 1, number of Nodes 2)
     / \ / \
    A  C E  G (incorrect answer at this depth) (depth 2, number of Nodes 4 but getting 1)
```

Node Definition Code:

```
public class simpleBST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
private Node root;             // root of BST

static boolean verbose = true;   // set to false to suppress positive test results
private class Node {
    private Key key;           // key
    private Value val;         // associated data
    private Node left, right;  // left and right subtrees

    public Node(Key key, Value val) {
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
    }
```

My Code

```
public int numNodesAtDepth(int d) {
return numNodesAtDepthHelper(root,d,0);
}
public int numNodesAtDepthHelper(Node temp,int d,int cdepth)
{
    if(temp==null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(cdepth==d)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return numNodesAtDepthHelper(temp.left,d,cdepth++) + numNodesAtDepthHelper(temp.right,d,cdepth++);
}
```

Test Code

```
testnumNodesAtDepth("DBACFEG",1, 2);
```

Result

testnumNodesAtDepthD: Correct   Keys: [ DBACFEG ]   actual: 2

Test Code

```
testnumNodesAtDepth("DBACFEG",2, 4);
```

Result

testnumNodesAtDepthD: *Error*   Keys: [ DBACFEG ]   expected: 4  actual: 1

The test code just creates a tree with the keys given and calls the method. With the format testnumNodesAtDepth("Keys"(nodes) to be passed in, depth, number of "keys"(nodes) at that depth);
What I'm confused about is how my code gets two different answers on the same tree and how I could fix this error.

Comment: The tree is created at the function testnumNodesAtDepth, and you are calling the numNodesAtDepth here.  Can you also add testnumNodesAtDepth function in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
return numNodesAtDepthHelper(temp.left,d,cdepth++) + numNodesAtDepthHelper(temp.right,d,cdepth++);
```

When you call `cdepth++`, it increases the value of cdepth and returns the old value. So, if cdepth is 1, the above line is equivalent to:

```
return numNodesAtDepthHelper(temp.left,d,1) + numNodesAtDepthHelper(temp.right,d,2);
```

The solution is to use `cdepth + 1` instead of `cdepth++`.

Comment: This was correct I did not know it kept the old value, thank you.